# Why is global state bad?

Tags: ruby, global-state

I had a talk with someone on the #ruby-lang channel the other day about `@@class_variables`. It all started when a user asked what's the best way to keep track of connected users to his server (I slightly simplified it, but that's the gist of it).

So, I suggested:

```
class User
  @@list = {} #assuming he wants to look up users by some type of ID

  def initialize(user_id, ...)
    @@list[user_id] = self
    #...
  end
end
```

However, somone said that the use of global state here is considered bad practice.

I understand why a global state is bad for something that relies on multiple back-ends, because the *global* part of global state stops being so global, and becomes localised to that one back-end. Or that it interferes with dependency injection.

I really can't think of any other reason why this is bad, though. And, if concurrency ever becomes an issue (there's a need for multiple back-ends), then we can update the code to use Redis (or something similar).

Also, I found [this question on programmers.sxc](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil), but it doesn't help me understand why the above code is considered so bad? Also, what would be the alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Why is it bad?

Global state is bad for a couple of reasons you didn't mention:

1. **It's Unreliable**: Because anything in your program, including third party code, can change the variable, you can never depend on something being there one second after you put it in.
2. **It breaks encapsulation**: If have a global list of users, other parts of the program should have to go through the User class to access it. Otherwise, everyone is manipulating data directly, which is a bad idea.
3. **Hard to change**: If you find out that your global state needs to be, say, an array instead of a hash, bad luck. You have to change every part of the code that uses it because there are no accessors to change.
4. This one is a little more abstract, but still: **Function Purity**: When you introduce global state, many previously pure functions become impure. This is bad in general, because compiled languages like C can heavily optimize pure functions, and bad in Ruby because it makes methods much harder to test.

The specific form of global state you mention, `@@` variables, is also bad for a Ruby specific reason:

- **It has weird inheritance semantics**: `@@` variables in Ruby are shared between a class and all it's subclasses. So even though you think that it is encapsulated, it isn't. This is especially bad if someone subclasses your `User` class, and declares a variable `@@list` for storing unrelated data. Ruby won't complain, and the state of the entire User class tree is compromised.

---

## What else can be done?

- **Dependancy Injection**: Just pass around the data to whoever needs it without ever maintaining it globally.
- **Class Encapsulation**: If you need global state, have a class maintain it with setters and getters. This invalidates points 2 and 3, along with the `@@` probelm because it uses class `@` variables. Example:

  ```
  class User
    class << self
      @list = {}
      def add_user(uid, user)
        #Do validation here
        @list[uid] = user
      end
      #More methods like add_user
    end
    def initialize(user_id, ...)
      User.add_user(user_id, self)
    end
  end
  ```

Comment: Okay.  So, I understood all of your points, but I am still confused about one thing: How do I keep track of all connected users if there is not some type of list that would reference them? I've actually used the encapsulation method a fee times in my projects to store similar data. I just can't think of a way to do it without maintaining some type of list! :(

Comment: @destiel: why can't you use the class encapsulation method? Its still global, just with better access rules and easier changing and refactoring.

Comment: That is what I wanted to know, too! I previously used the class encapsulation method on some projects.The asker had a v. simple problem to solve, and the @@variable would have been sufficient, but someone claimed it was completely wrong because of the global state. I was just curious why it was so horrendous that it couldn't *ever* be used (not even when encapsulating the class),  and whether there was an alternative solution to the problem. Edit: the person who complained didn't mind about the class variable, though (not directly at least).